# How to change order state after paypal payment?

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, payment-methods, order-status, paypal-standard

Using standard paypal payments, after a paypal payment is made, orders are set to "processing" (`Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING`). I need to set a different state/status, as follows:

```
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_HOLDED, 'payment_accepted');
```

However, I have been unable to find an appropriate observer, or another place to set the state/status.

How can this be achieved when paypal payment is complete?

Currently, the site uses paypal standard, but will likely migrate to a different paypal setup soon. The site will likely use this same logic for other payment methods.